# Python перевод числа в восьмеричную систему счисления

Tags: python

Напиши программу, которая получает на вход в единственной строке целое десятичное число и осуществляет перевод этого числа в восьмеричную систему счисления.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

В Python есть встроенная функция `oct()`

Пример использования:

```
a = int(input("Введите десятичное число>"))
print("Восьмеричное число: %s"  %  oct(a))
```